# lxml.etree: get the entity name without expanding it

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have the following XML:

```
<!ENTITY abbr "abbreviation">
<pos>&abbr;</pos>
```

I would like to get the "untouched" inner XML content of the `pos` node (i.e. `&abbr;`)

The following approaches do not work:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False)
doc = etree.parse(inFile, parser)
print doc.find("pos").text # ! this prints "None"
print etree.tostring(doc.find("pos")) # ! this prints "<pos>&abbr;</pos>"

doc = etree.parse(inputFile)
print doc.find("pos").text # ! this prints "abbreviation"
```

Any simple solution ?

Comment: Can you post a complete minimal example instead of just a fragment that `lxml` can't parse?

Comment: @MattH: this is an exact duplicate indeed. I find the solution a bit surprising, but it works :)