# Parse XML in Python but ignoring entity

Tags: python, xml

I have to pase an XML file and store data into a database. The problem is this XML have some entity that I don't wanto to import but, instead, I want the raw entity tag. To clarify better I have the following schema:

```
<!ENTITY exa "example">
.....
<mytag>&exa;</mytag>
```

If I try to parse the above code reading the tag "mytag" using the folliwng code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root:
        if item.tag == "mytag":
```

I read the string "example". Instead I want to have the tag "exa". I guess is possible but cause I'm new t python delelompent I can not find the right way to get this result.
Some suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a more specific example of your XML? Did you try to read the "text" attribute of your element?

Comment: String returned by item.text (follow the example) is "example" as normally should be. Instead I woudl to get "exa".

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685643/lxml-etree-get-the-entity-name-without-expanding-it?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: At first I really thank you for try helping me. I checked the topic you linked but it seem the ElementTree.XMLParser doesn't support the resolve_entities=False param. Maybe I'm making something wrong?
New code should be:
parser = ET.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False)    tree = ET.parse(file, parser=parser)

Comment: Because it's `lxml` library, bot `xml`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to start:

```
import os
import re
from lxml import etree

xmlfile = 'testfile.xml'
xml_path = '%s/%s' % (os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), xmlfile)

parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False)
tree = etree.parse(xml_path, parser)
# root = tree.getroot()

root = tree.xpath('/mytag')

for item in root:
    entity = etree.tostring(item, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8')
    print('ENTITY     : ', entity)
    entity_value = re.findall(r'&(.*?);', entity)
    print('Parsed str : ', entity_value)
```

But there may be a simpler way to recover the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify each of the `ENTITY` tags in the xml file so that they have the values you want in them and then modify them back at the end.

You could create a class that clones your xml file:

```py
import os
import re

class NoEntities:
    """
    Creates a clone of the target xml file such that the <!ENTITY x "y"> tags
    become <!ENTITY x "x">.
    """

    def __init__(self, xmlFile):
        self.targetName = xmlFile
        self.tmpName = 'temp.xml'

    def __enter__(self):
        match = r'<!ENTITY\s+(\S+)\s+"[^"]+"\s*>'
        replace = r'<!ENTITY \1 "\1">'

        with open(self.targetName) as target:
            with open(self.tmpName, 'w') as tmp:
                tmp.writelines(
                    re.sub(match, replace, line)
                    for line in target
                )

        return self.tmpName

    def __exit__(self, *exec_info):
        os.remove(self.tmpName)
```

And then use it inside a with block:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with NoEntities(pathToOriginalXml) as noEntityXml:
    tree = ET.parse(noEntityXml)
    # Do what you like...
```